# Maven stuck during compilation

Tags: maven, build

I am using mvn clean install command and seems like maven goes into some deadlock while compiling classes, it remains in this state -

```
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ service-nextgen ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ service-nextgen ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 363 source files to C:\Users\service-nextgen\target\classes
```

If I visualize thread dump using java Visual VM, I get following information:

```
"RMI TCP Connection(3)-3.202.32.1" #20 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001f246000 nid=0x2454 runnable [0x000000002118e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    - locked <0x00000000ff832010> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:550)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$240(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$2/10873147.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000000ff8321d0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)


"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000001ff8000 nid=0x2b38 runnable [0x0000000002501000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Object.hashCode(Native Method)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:556)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Infer$InferenceContext.cachedCapture(Infer.java:2309)
```

not sure how to get the root cause.

Comment: Are you trying to do `mvn clean install` on plain command line? I don't know where this RMI connection is comming from ?

Comment: was able to identify the issue after adding Compiler args in maven compiler plugin:  
<compilerArgs>
           <arg>-verbose</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg>
</compilerArgs>

This displayed the classes one by one during compilation and was able to see where compiler was getting stuck.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html

Comment: Can you set the [`fork` property](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#fork) to `true` (`-Dmaven.compiler.fork=true`). This may help in narrowing down whether the the problem is with Maven or `javac` itself. (When running `mvn` with `-X`, it also prints out the `javac` command line it uses, so you can eliminate Maven from the equation entirely by running `javac` yourself.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to identify the issue after adding Compiler args in maven compiler plugin: `<compilerArgs> <arg>-verbose</arg> <arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg> </compilerArgs>` This displayed the classes one by one during compilation and I was able to see where compiler was getting stuck.

The maven configuration looks something like [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html):

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-verbose</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

One possible class of culprits for errors of this kind are [Annotations Processors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) which generate code during the compilation phase.

Answer (score 1):

I got and googled the problem "Maven stuck during installation", then I was directed to this question. Now my problem is solved, and I want to share my exprience here.

First, thanks to @Rhishi 's answer, I know how to locate the stuck point.
Second, my solution is **"do clean first, then compile and install"**. I am not sure whether it works for everybody, but it works for me and worthes a try.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting my maven stuck forever in the Discovery starting.
The issue was caused by a search and replace that created something like this:

```scala
object Foo {
  def bar: String = Foo.bar
  // ...
}
```

No error, no messages, just stuck forever.
The solution, of course, is properly creating the attribute.

```scala
object Foo {
  def bar: String = "bar"
  // ...
}
```